# Predicting over/under score with Python

Tags: python, model

I want to build a model that predicts if the total score of two players is above or below a certain score or what the probability is that it's below or above that certain score.

The only data I have is the previous TOTAL scores from all of the players previous matches (not each players individual score), which is an average of 10. Currently I create a KDE from each of the player's previous scores and then use those two to create a sample of scores which I use to create a third KDE which I then use to calculate the CDF of the target score.

The scores are always positive integers or zero, the average is about 10 and rarely does it go over 20. Am I even thinking about this problem correctly? I would like to know what the correct method is for developing a model for this situation.

Simple answers appreciated.